# Tornado http server - Failed to load response data - React app chunks

Tags: python, reactjs, tornado, httpserver, chunks

Setting up a Tornado web server for a React app, and the chunks fail to load.

Puzzling, as app loads and works with Node's `http-server -p 1800` and Python's `python -m http.server 1800`

As you can see, I have added some CORS headings to the Tornado server, but still pretty basic.

```
  1 import tornado.web
  2 import tornado.ioloop
  3
  4 class StaticHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
  5
  6     def set_default_headers(self):
  7         print("setting headers")
  8         self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
  9         self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with")
 10         self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", 'POST, GET, OPTIONS')
 11
 12     def get(self):
 13         print("Rendering index.html")
 14         self.render("index.html")
 15
 16 if __name__ == '__main__':
 17
 18     app = tornado.web.Application([
 19         (r"/", StaticHandler),
 20     ])
 21     app.listen(1800)
 22     print("Listening on port 1800")
 23     tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

[image: Network]

Answer (score 0):

Tornado isn't serving these files because you haven't asked it to - you only told it to serve your `StaticHandler` (not to be confused with Tornado's `StaticFileHandler`) on `/`. The usual way to do this is to pass `static_path` to the `Application` constructor, but this will serve the files under `/static/*.js`. If you really want to serve these files straight off the root, you can do it by adding a route for `("/(.*)", tornado.web.StaticFileHandler, dict(path="."))`

Also remember that this will serve the source code to your application as well. If you don't want that, use a different directory for your static path from your python code.